# How do I merge 3 tables in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I have 3 tables in a MySQL database. 
Table t1 and t2 have the same identical rows and share a common field X. 
Table t3 has a smaller number of rows and shares a common field with table t1, say field Z. 
All rows from table t3 have a corresponding row in both tables t1 and t2 (but Field Z is shared only with table t1)

What I want is a query that will link these tables and output a table that has all the columns from each table, and ALL the rows from table t1 (for that matter t2 also because all rows correspond).

I have this statement from a previous question that effectively links table t1 and t3 and outputs all the rows from table t1 together with the columns in t3.

```
  SELECT t1.*,
       t3.* 
  FROM t1
  LEFT JOIN t3
  ON t1.X = t3.Z
```

But now I also need to include all the columns from t2.
How would I do this? (hope it makes sense...)

Thank you.

Comment: I'm confused. If tables 1 and 2 "*have the same identical rows*", doesn't it mean that they have the same set of fields?  I think you will be better off by providing a sample data and the expected result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT t1.*, t2.*, t3.*
FROM t1
JOIN t2 ON t1.X = t2.X
LEFT JOIN t3 ON t1.X = t3.Z
```

Comment: Why is that you perform a `JOIN` first and then a `LEFT JOIN`? Thanks

Comment: `LEFT JOIN` is used when there might not be matching rows in the table you're joining with. Since `t1` and `t2` have all the same rows, there's no need to use a `LEFT JOIN` for `t2`. The default `INNER JOIN` is more efficient.